# I want to insert data into table storeuser from table store and table user

Tags: mysql, database, create-table

I have three tables: `store`, `users` and `storeuser`.

Table `storeuser` has Foreigns keys of `store`  and `users` tables.

The three tables have id columns as `storeid`, `userid`, `suserid` and are on auto-increment for the said id columns.

Now I want to insert data into table `storeuser` from table `store` and table `user`:

```
CREATE TABLE `store2`.`store` (
  `storeid` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sname` CHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `stype` CHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `location` CHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`storeid`));

CREATE TABLE `store2`.`users` (
  `userid` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `uname` CHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `age` SMALLINT(5) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`userid`));

CREATE TABLE `store2`.`storeuser` (
  `suserid` INT(10) NOT NULL,
  `storeid` INT(10) NOT NULL,
  `userid` INT(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`suserid`),
  INDEX `storeid_idx` (`storeid` ASC),
  INDEX `userid_idx` (`userid` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `storeid`
    FOREIGN KEY (`storeid`)
    REFERENCES `store2`.`store` (`storeid`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `userid`
    FOREIGN KEY (`userid`)
    REFERENCES `store2`.`users` (`userid`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION);
```

Comment: what should be the value of suserid in the table storeuser? It's a primary key and not an auto-increment. So what value should be here?

Comment: suserud is on auto-increment ...it should start with 1

Comment: the suserid is on auto-increment , now plz guide me

Comment: i have added auto-increment to suserid...now plz guide me...thanks in advance ..

Answer (score 0):

Your request is weird or maybe I don't understand it properly.

So basically, you want to have an ID called suserid (auto-increment) for each pair of storeid & userid (again auto-increment) which have no relation to each other?

I'm not sure I understand you well, but here's a solution as per my understanding:

```
mysql> select * from store;
+---------+-------+-------+----------+
| storeid | sname | stype | location |
+---------+-------+-------+----------+
|       1 | a     | b     | c        |
|       2 | a1    | b2    | c3       |
+---------+-------+-------+----------+

mysql> select * from users;
+--------+-------+-----+
| userid | uname | age |
+--------+-------+-----+
|      1 | 1     |   2 |
|      2 | 3     |   4 |
+--------+-------+-----+

mysql> desc storeuser;
+---------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| suserid | int(10) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| storeid | int(10) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| userid  | int(10) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+---------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Now I make the insert into storeuser:

```
mysql> insert into storeuser select '',storeid, userid from store join      
users on store.storeid=users.userid;
```

After INSERT:

```
mysql> select * from storeuser;
+---------+---------+--------+
| suserid | storeid | userid |
+---------+---------+--------+
|       1 |       1 |      1 |
|       2 |       2 |      2 |
+---------+---------+--------+
```

Is this what you need?

Comment: Mr.Krishnakumar.. but  the store table and user table are neither similar nor identical...no common columns among store and user tables..please guide me.....

Comment: That's what I was concerned about. What do you actually need here? Say for suserid 1, what you need to be storeid and userid ?

Comment: please check this ...Mr krishnakumar..suserid should fill on auto-increment and the data from store and users (where store has three records and users has four records) must be inserted into storeuser through query with WHERE clause....store---># storeid, sname, stype, location
'1', 'RF', 'Cp', 'h'-'2', 'JB', 'Rl', 's'-'3', 'B', 'C', 'g'                                                                                                         users---> #userid,uname,age  '1', 'j', '24'--'2', 's', '37'--'3', 'S', '27'--'4', 'z', '48'

Comment: @Arunad Will it be possible for you to add an example of of your expectation in the question itself? Like I have given in my answer? What you have in user table. What you have in Store and finally what you need in storeuser?

Comment: store---># storeid, sname, stype, location                                                           
                 ( '1', 'RF', 'Cp', 'h')('2', 'JB', 'Rl', 's')('3', 'B', 'C', 'g' )                  users---> #userid,uname,age( '1', 'j', '24')('2', 's', '37')('3', 'S', '27')('4', 'z','48') ......this data from 2 tables to be inserted into storeuser table ...Mr KRISHNAKUMAR....thank you

Comment: From your above example: the result in the store table woulds be the same one in my answer...

Comment: Mr.krishnakumar..can i have your e-mail id please

Comment: @krishnakumar..can i have your e-mail id please..i am getting 1366 incorrect integer value..when i gave the above query through which data is put into storeuser table.

Comment: @Arunad I can't share the id publicly... That's why I asked you to edit it in the question itself... You'll have more options to show what error you are getting.. give me live sample of all your 3 tables...

Comment: this data from 2 tables to be inserted into storeuser table
store--->
# storeid, sname, stype, location 
( '1', 'RF', 'Cp', 'hyd'), ('2', 'JB', 'Rl', 'sbad'), ('3', 'B', 'C', 'gtr' ) 
users--->
 #userid,uname,age
( '1', 'j', '24'), ('2', 's', '37'), ('3', 'S', '27'),('4', 'z','48')   @krishnakumar my mail - arunagames1@gmail.com